# What is the trailing 'm' on fuser's output?

Tags: bash, gnu, command-line-tool

I'd like to list process' which use "/dev/my/dev". (Device name is an example)
So I've used fuser:

```
$ fuser /dev/my/dev

/dev/my/dev:  19228m 19268 21620 21623 21663
```

**Note the trailing 'm'.**

If I redirect stderr, it's gone:

```
$ fuser /dev/my/dev 2>/dev/null 

 19228 19268 21620 21623 21663
```

What is this trailing 'm' doing here? Why is it reported to stderr?

fuser's version is:

```
$ fuser --version
fuser (PSmisc) 22.20
Copyright (C) 1993-2010 Werner Almesberger and Craig Small
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m` signifies a memory-mapped (`mmap`) file or shared library.

The [fuser manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fuser.1.html) notes:

> fuser outputs only the PIDs to stdout, everything else is sent to stderr.

Hence, the behavior you see when STDERR is redirected to the bit-bucket.